# touching a path name with varriable or other methode

Tags: linux, shell, path, directory

I have a question about touching a path in a shell script. I'm making a script that clears some directories and add some files, now I'm trying to do this with `touch /name/of/path` instead of a `find`. I have some troubles with one of the paths this is becaus the last bit of the name changes in every file (the files are about working orders)  now I tried some stuff like a variable or just the path with a `*` but it gives me an error

can anyone tell me if i need to change my variable for example.
the variable im currently using:

```
test='path/to/touch/annoy\ ing\ space*/'
```

and in my code I would like to execute this like

```
touch $test/test.txt
```

the error I get when running this is

```
touch: invalid option --'\'
```

I guess i get this option because there are \ in the varriabe but that is because there are spaces in the directory name I'm trying to enter.

I also tried something like this

```
touch path/to/touch/annoy\ ing\ space*/test.txt
```

but I also get an error when I try it like this, I read this is because I use a wildcard in touch and that isn't allowed. Can anyone confirm this?

If someone could give me an example or tip how to do this it would realy help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: use double quotes in your `touch` statement: `touch "$test/test.txt"`

Comment: @Renardo when use double quotes I get the error `touch: cannot touch /path/i/want/to/touch.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: So it looks like your directory structure does not exist yet. In order to create it first call `mkdir -p "$test"`. `touch` only creates files, not directories.

Comment: yea I know but i want to make a file not a directory, that's why I use touch

Comment: Your description says you want to create a file (`touch.txt`) in a directory (`$test`). So in order to create the file you first need the directory. `touch` does not create it, you need `mkdir`for that. Did you try what I recommended? First call `mkdir -p "$test"`, then call `touch "$test/touch.txt"`?

Comment: no I would like to create `test.txt` `$test` is a variable with a path in it so the path does exist

Comment: OK, so you say your path exists, the error message *(no such file or directory)* says it does not. Only one of you can be right. You could eliminate all doubts by calling `mkdir` but you do not want to, so I cannot help you. Sorry.